# Issue with XSD_STRING_HOLDER value. How to get the result in a string?

Tags: lotusscript

I've a problem in WebserviceConsumer with XSD_STRING_HOLDER. How to get the result in a string?

```
Dim soapClient As New Servicewebbacarasoap_n17
Dim strFluxResponse As New XSD_STRING_HOLDER
Dim response As XSD_STRING
Dim strRequest As New XSD_STRING
Dim strCodeRetour As String, strFluxXMLSortant As String
soapClient.Setendpoint("http:....?wsdl") 
strRequest.Setvaluefromstring("<ROOT><PAram 2>VOIP</PAram 2><Param 1>C</Param 1></ROOT>")
Set response = soapclient.Consolidationsacre(strRequest, strFluxResponse)
strCodeRetour = response.Getvalueasstring
strFluxXMLSortant = strFluxResponse.Value.Getvalueasstring
Msgbox strFluxXMLSortant
```

When strFluxResponse is "test" it is ok. But when when strFluxResponse returns "`<ROOT><PasswordTunnel>MOTDEPASSE</PasswordTunnel></ROOT>`" msgbox returns nothing...

%INCLUDE "lsxsd.lss"
Const n17 = "http://localhost/soap/"
Class ServiceWebBacaraSoap_n17 As PortTypeBase

```
Sub NEW
    Call Service.Initialize ("HttpLocalhostSoapServiceWebBacara", _
    "ServiceWebBacara.ServiceWebBacaraSoap", "http://##FermeAsyncWebService##/binSacreAsyncDotNet/WebServices/ServiceWebBacara.asmx", _
    "ServiceWebBacaraSoap_n17")

End Sub

Function consolidationSACRE(p_ChaineXML_s As XSD_STRING, p_ChaineXMLSortie_s As XSD_STRING_Holder) As XSD_STRING
    Set consolidationSACRE = Service.Invoke("consolidationSACRE", p_ChaineXML_s, p_ChaineXMLSortie_s)
End Function

Function superviser() As XSD_STRING
    Set superviser = Service.Invoke("superviser")
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: This might be a silly question, but if the msgbox is not showing you the strFluxResponse, then how do you know that the service is really returning "<ROOT><PasswordTunnel>MOTDEPASSE</PasswordTunnel></ROOT>"?

Comment: No not silly question ;-). I use Soap UI for my webservice provider.

Comment: Are you running the SoapUI test on the same machine that you are running your consumer on, so no differences in proxy, firewall, etc.? And what do you get if you add a MsgBox to also output strCodeRetour?

Comment: Not on the same machine. strCodeRetour is running, it returns "ok".

Comment: Well, I guess I'd probably want to try capturing the actual SOAP transaction data to be sure that the strFluxResponse is really coming back as expected when the call is made from the actual machine. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Here is the webservice consumer :